# Binding params with Kohana's Database library

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, database, parameterized

I know I can bind params in Kohana like this

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?', array(14));
```

But is there a way to do it with identifiers (or whatever they are called?)

As in

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = :id', array(':id' => 14));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.x has no support for it, but 3.x supports it. See [this forum post](http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=3587&page=1#Comment_27015).

Answer (score 2):

that functionality is available in the new 2.4/3.0 versions of Kohana, the current 2.3 release does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty positive Kohana does not do this. When looking at the Database class, all bound parameters are handled in a method called `compile_binds`... Looks like it only supports the `?` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish they would support it.